# how to let a minimized form to notify user to open it from taskbar?

Tags: c#, winforms, notifications

I'm developing a small chat application between client and server.

I would like to get notified when a message received and the chat window is minimized (like in live messenger)

[image]

here's the method that I append the received message onto.

```
public void AppendChat(string msg)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<string>(AppendChat), new object[] { msg });
        return;
    }
    txtChat.AppendText(GetTime() + msg + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
    if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        //... what should I write in here?
    }
}
```

sorry for my bad English. I hope I wrote the right words for the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool FlashWindowEx(ref FLASHWINFO pwfi);
```

Use the user32 method to flash the window.
You can read more about the method and it's parametrs [here](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/01/26/CSharp-Flash-Window-in-Taskbar-via-Win32-FlashWindowEx.aspx).
It has a complete code and examples for how to use it.