# show count on minimized windows of your application in c#

Tags: c#

Actually, I want something like skype does. if someone send two messages on skype; you see number "2" on minimized skype window. So, I want to know how can I show number/counts on minimized window of your c# application?

Comment: what you mean by `show on minimized windows`? do you mean show on the taskbar icon? if you want to show on the taskbar icon just change the icon to new icon with the text overlaid.

Comment: You mean the WIndows 7/8 taskbar icons?

Comment: just have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970207/how-to-let-a-minimized-form-to-notify-user-to-open-it-from-taskbar

Comment: @BibyAugustine that is to flash the icon.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182693/how-to-do-overlay-icons-on-the-taskbar-in-windows-7-for-net

Comment: i think this will work... http://iandotnet.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/minimize-application-to-system-tray-c/ :)

Comment: I mean count on the application icon/button(when we run app its icon available at taskbar)

Comment: you can use tooltip or notifyicon to show the message on minimizing the window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using WPF, you can use the [TaskbarButtonInfo.Overlay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff823754.aspx) property.

```
// draw an image to overlay
var dg = new DrawingGroup();
var dc = dg.Open();
dc.DrawEllipse(Brushes.Blue, new Pen(Brushes.LightBlue, 1), new Point(8, 8), 8, 8);
dc.DrawText(new FormattedText("3", System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    new Typeface("Arial"), 16, Brushes.White), new Point(4, 0));
dc.Close();
var geometryImage = new DrawingImage(dg);
geometryImage.Freeze();

// set on this window
var tbi = new TaskbarItemInfo();
tbi.Overlay = geometryImage;

this.TaskbarItemInfo = tbi;
```

Produces
[image: Taskbar button with an overlay of a circled number 3]

If you are using Windows Forms, use Windows API Code Pack as documented in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182693/how-to-do-overlay-icons-on-the-taskbar-in-windows-7-for-net).

Comment: I used code pack API. will my app will run on xp ? because code pack is windows 7 API and it needs win7 environment.

Comment: Taking a reference on it will not restrict it from running on XP, but you may get exceptions when calling code which requires later OS versions.

Comment: @Mitch - This is **sooo close** to what I want, but is there any way to position the overlay so that it's **perfectly centred** on the bottom-right corner of the taskbar icon? I know I'm being pedantic and will settle for this if it's the only way, but yeah...Win 10 apps from the store can do what I want so why can't I?!

Comment: @Kenny83, what makes you think that UWP has access to any different tools? Both the base icon and the overlay are just images.  The overlay is at a fixed offset you do not control, but if you want them to line up you can adjust your two images to make that happen.  (You can also just skip using overlay icons and change the base icon instead.)

Comment: @Mitch - Yeah didn't think there was anything different about official Store apps, hence my last sentence. I guess the MSFT designers are just better at their job than I am at designing images, which doesn't surprise me at all lol. In particular I'm talking about the Mail app...trying to use its icon and unread mail badge overlays but having trouble lining up the latter. Oh well, I guess I'll just have to live with it being a few pixels off centre.