# WinForms - Show notification count in app launcher Icon

Tags: winforms, count, notifications, icons, app-launcher

In my WinForms application, I want to display the notifications count in the app launcher icon.

How can this be achieved ?

Comment: What is a *app launcher Icon* in Windows desktop OS? Are you talking about shortcut?

Comment: No, the icon that shows on bottom (along with start button) when an application is running.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21129764/2530848) is what you're asking for, unfortunately it is in WPF. Winforms doesn't provide a way to do that. You need to P/Invoke manually.

Download [Windows 7 API Code Pack - Shell](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Windows7APICodePack-Shell/)
 and use the following.

```
private void SetTaskBarOverlay()
{
    string notificationCount = "3"; //To do: Add this as a parameter

    var bmp = new Bitmap(32, 32);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
        g.DrawString(notificationCount, new Font("Sans serif", 25, GraphicsUnit.Point),
            Brushes.White, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
    }

    var overlay = Icon.FromHandle(bmp.GetHicon());
    TaskbarManager.Instance.SetOverlayIcon(overlay, "");
}

private void RemoveTaskBarOverlay()
{
    TaskbarManager.Instance.SetOverlayIcon(null, "");
}
```

You may alter the painting code to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: This is what I am looking for exactly. I downloaded code pack & added in my project. Also added using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell; in my cs file, but couldn't access TaskbarManager yet. Am I missing anything ?

Comment: umm, You did it manually or used nuget? I used nuget and that worked for me well. You need its dependant package as well. What is the error you get?

Comment: I added to my project thru nugget - PM command. App cant recognize TaskbarManager. 'The name TaskbarManager does not exist in current context.

Comment: In references, I can see Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack . I read here - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/65185/Windows-Taskbar-C-Quick-Reference  , so also added PresentationCore, PresentationFramework & windowsBase dll's. But, no success.

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5 version.